# How to check by ID if data has already been output to the website to avoid duplication

Tags: php, mysql, loops, while-loop

I need to output questions from my database so users can answer them as part of the registration process. Each question has 2 choices related to it, and each question is now being outputted to the site twice each with one choice below it. I need each question to appear once with their related choices appearing below it. Please see my code below.

```
   <?php
       $sql = "SELECT Question_ID, Question FROM Questions;";

       $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
       $resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);

       if($resultCheck > 0):
          while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)):
             $questionid = (int)$row['Question_ID'];
            ?>
            <label><?php echo $row['Question'];?></label><input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $row['Question_ID'];?>"/>
   <?php
             $query = "SELECT Choice_ID, Choice FROM Choices WHERE Question_ID = '$questionid';";
             $results = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
             $resultsCheck = mysqli_num_rows($results);
               if($resultsCheck > 0):
                  while($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results)):
        ?>
         <br><select id="choice">
            <option value="<?php echo $rows['Choice_ID']; ?>"><?php echo $rows['Choice']; ?></option>
        </select><br/>
        <?php
        endwhile;
        endif;
        endwhile;
        endif;
        ?>
```

Comment: Questions are printed in the inner loop, thus may be displayed multiple times. Move printing of q. before the inner loop

Comment: @EriksKlotins I have edited the code above. One question is displayed but each choice is now displayed in separate select tags

Comment: See about prepared statements - and joins!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You do not have any `<form>` in your question and I suppose you know what you are doing and you know how to handle the posted data since your `<input>` and `<select>` elements does not have any `name` properties.
2. As Strawberry suggested, it's recommended to use prepared statements.

I have changed your code just a little to meet your needs, In your code, you have to take the `<select>` tag out of the `while` loop and just have the `<option>` tags in the loop.

So the code will be like this:

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT Question_ID, Question FROM Questions;";

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);

if($resultCheck > 0):
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)):
        $questionid = (int)$row['Question_ID'];
        echo '<label>'.$row['Question'].'</label><input type="hidden" value="'.$row['Question_ID'].'">';

        $query = "SELECT Choice_ID, Choice FROM Choices WHERE Question_ID = '$questionid';";
        $results = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
        $resultsCheck = mysqli_num_rows($results);
        if($resultsCheck > 0):
            $string = '<br><select id="choice">';
            while($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results)):
                $string .= '<option value="'.$rows['Choice_ID'].'">'.$rows['Choice'].'</option>';
            endwhile;
            $string .= '</select><br>';
            echo $string;
        endif;
    endwhile;
endif;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Organize your code like this (simplified for readability)

```
while($question = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
   echo "<label for='q'>...; // print question
   echo "<select name='answer'>"  
   while ($answer = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results))
   {
       echo '<option>'.$answer.</option>';
   }
   echo '</select>';
}
```